# Home movie video browser

Tags: windows, video, software-rec, file-management, viewer

I have a bunch of home movies that don't have useful filenames because they came straight off the camera.  (I'm using Vista 64, by the way.)

Picasa is pretty good for browsing through them and watching them, but it doesn't use my video card for rendering the videos. My CPU gets pegged at max usage, and full screen barely works. Windows Media Player or Quicktime works fine.

Is there another application (like Picasa) that can be used for browsing through movies that both uses my video card and shows thumbnails of all the movies in my collection? I'd rather have something nicer than Windows Explorer.

(The movies are h.264 AAC 1280x720.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxee has some slick local file browsing. I use it on the mac, but I've heard its just the same on the PC.

http://www.boxee.tv/

Answer (score 0):

Download [Shark's Codecs](http://shark007.net/) and you can use Windows Live PhotoGallery.